# Android Sample Project cannot be built on my Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image][image: Screenshot]

I download the Sample Project from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo?autodive=0%2F

However, I cannot build it or do anything with it (it's gray). I guess it's about the version of my Android Studio or something. I'm using Mac OS X, Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: Check the wifidirectActivity file, the on you are showing on the image is a decompiled class and you can not run that one.

Comment: I added a new image.

Comment: Your project looks to be a eclipse project, theres a option to "import eclipse project" dont remember where, it should fix it (creates the gradle files)